# How to open NavigationDrawer only on first app start?

Tags: android, design-patterns, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

Per Google guidelines, it is recommended you open the `DrawerLayout` the first time only after app is installed and opened (to show user the functionality).

*How would you go about doing this?*

It seems it would be a combination of `openDrawer()` method with some type of preference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would recommend that you use the **SharedPreferences** for that:

> **The basic idea is that you read the SharedPreferences and look for a boolean value that doesn't exist there at first app start.** By
>   default, you will return "true" if the value you were looking for
>   could not be found, indicating that it is in fact the first app start. Then, after your first app start you will store the value
>   "false" in your SharedPreferences, and upon next start, the value
>   "false" will be read from the SharedPreferences, indicating that it is
>   no longer the first app start.

Here is an example of how it could look like:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // your other code...
    // setContentView(...) initialize drawer and stuff like that...

    // use thread for performance
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            SharedPreferences sp = Context.getSharedPreferences("yoursharedprefs", 0);
            boolean isFirstStart = sp.getBoolean("key", true); 
            // we will not get a value  at first start, so true will be returned

            // if it was the first app start
            if(isFirstStart) {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
                Editor e = sp.edit(); 
                // we save the value "false", indicating that it is no longer the first appstart
                e.putBoolean("key", false);
                e.commit();
            }
        }           
    });

    t.start();
}
```