# Getting runtime error for my android studio project

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I was modified my MainActivity code to open navigation-drawer when app launches.But that attempt did not worked and I undo all the changes.Still I getting error while running app.How can I solve this error? also help me to open navigation-drawer on app launch.

This is the code I used for that purpose

```
static final int DRAWER_DELAY = 200;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    // Building NavDrawer logic here. Just a method call would be best.
    ...
    new Handler().postDelayed(openDrawerRunnable(), DRAWER_DELAY);
}

private Runnable openDrawerRunnable() {
    return new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my MainActivity code

```
package com.example.mohammedalukkal.ktucses4;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.text.style.BackgroundColorSpan;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
            implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        private static long time;
        FloatingActionButton fab,fab_univer,fab_drive,fab_web;
        TextView university,ktuweb,drive;
        Animation Fabopen,Fabclose,Fabclockwise,Fabanticlockwise,dimon,dimoff;
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
        boolean isopen = false;
        ImageView dim;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            university = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.university);
            ktuweb = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ktuweb);
            drive = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.drive);
            fab_drive = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_drive);
            fab_web = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_web);
            fab_univer = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_univer);
            Fabopen = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fab_open);
            Fabclose = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fab_close);
            Fabclockwise = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotate_clockwise);
            Fabanticlockwise = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotate_anticlockwise);
            dim = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dim);
            dimon = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.dim_on);
            dimoff = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.dim_off);

            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (isopen) {
                        university.startAnimation(Fabclose);
                        ktuweb.startAnimation(Fabclose);
                        drive.startAnimation(Fabclose);
                        fab.startAnimation(Fabanticlockwise);
                        fab_univer.startAnimation(Fabclose);
                        fab_web.startAnimation(Fabclose);
                        fab_drive.startAnimation(Fabclose);
                        dim.startAnimation(dimoff);
                        dim.setClickable(false);
                        fab_web.setClickable(false);
                        fab_univer.setClickable(false);
                        fab_drive.setClickable(false);
                        isopen = false;


                    } else {
                        university.startAnimation(Fabopen);
                        ktuweb.startAnimation(Fabopen);
                        drive.startAnimation(Fabopen);
                        fab.startAnimation(Fabclockwise);
                        fab_univer.startAnimation(Fabopen);
                        fab_web.startAnimation(Fabopen);
                        fab_drive.startAnimation(Fabopen);
                        dim.startAnimation(dimon);
                        dim.setClickable(true);
                        fab_web.setClickable(true);
                        fab_univer.setClickable(true);
                        fab_drive.setClickable(true);
                        isopen = true;


                    }

                }
            });

            fab_univer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),University.class));

                    if (isopen)
                    {
                        university.startAnimation(Fabclose);
                        ktuweb.startAnimation(Fabclose);
                        drive.startAnimation(Fabclose);
                        fab.startAnimation(Fabanticlockwise);
                        fab_univer.startAnimation(Fabclose);
                        fab_web.startAnimation(Fabclose);
                        fab_drive.startAnimation(Fabclose);
                        dim.startAnimation(dimoff);
                        dim.setClickable(false);
                        fab_web.setClickable(false);
                        fab_univer.setClickable(false);
                        fab_drive.setClickable(false);
                        isopen = false;
                    }

                }
            });
            fab_web.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Ktuweb.class));

                    if (isopen)
                    {
                        university.startAnimation(Fabclose);
                        ktuweb.startAnimation(Fabclose);
                        drive.startAnimation(Fabclose);
                        fab.startAnimation(Fabanticlockwise);
                        fab_univer.startAnimation(Fabclose);
                        fab_web.startAnimation(Fabclose);
                        fab_drive.startAnimation(Fabclose);
                        dim.startAnimation(dimoff);
                        dim.setClickable(false);
                        fab_web.setClickable(false);
                        fab_univer.setClickable(false);
                        fab_drive.setClickable(false);
                        isopen = false;
                    }
                }
            });
            fab_drive.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Drive.class));

                    if (isopen)
                    {
                        university.startAnimation(Fabclose);
                        ktuweb.startAnimation(Fabclose);
                        drive.startAnimation(Fabclose);
                        fab.startAnimation(Fabanticlockwise);
                        fab_univer.startAnimation(Fabclose);
                        fab_web.startAnimation(Fabclose);
                        fab_drive.startAnimation(Fabclose);
                        dim.startAnimation(dimoff);
                        dim.setClickable(false);
                        fab_web.setClickable(false);
                        fab_univer.setClickable(false);
                        fab_drive.setClickable(false);
                        isopen = false;
                    }
                }
            });



            final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.syncState();

            NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

            dim.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (isopen)
                    {
                        university.startAnimation(Fabclose);
                        ktuweb.startAnimation(Fabclose);
                        drive.startAnimation(Fabclose);
                        fab.startAnimation(Fabanticlockwise);
                        fab_univer.startAnimation(Fabclose);
                        fab_web.startAnimation(Fabclose);
                        fab_drive.startAnimation(Fabclose);
                        dim.startAnimation(dimoff);
                        dim.setClickable(false);
                        fab_web.setClickable(false);
                        fab_univer.setClickable(false);
                        fab_drive.setClickable(false);
                        isopen = false;
                    }
                }

            });

        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
            else if (isopen) {
                university.startAnimation(Fabclose);
                ktuweb.startAnimation(Fabclose);
                drive.startAnimation(Fabclose);
                fab.startAnimation(Fabanticlockwise);
                fab_univer.startAnimation(Fabclose);
                fab_web.startAnimation(Fabclose);
                fab_drive.startAnimation(Fabclose);
                dim.startAnimation(dimoff);
                dim.setClickable(false);
                fab_web.setClickable(false);
                fab_univer.setClickable(false);
                fab_drive.setClickable(false);
                isopen = false;
            }
            else {
                if (time + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                    super.onBackPressed();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Press back again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }





        @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle navigation view model clicks here.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            if (id == R.id.sub_1) {

                fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame,new ma202Fragment());
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("MA202");
                getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("Probability distributions,Transforms and Numerical Methods");


            } else if (id == R.id.sub_2) {

                fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame,new cs202Fragment());
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("CS202");
                getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("Computer Organization and Architecture");

            } else if (id == R.id.sub_3) {

                fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame,new cs204Fragment());
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("CS204");
                getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("Operating Systems");

            } else if (id == R.id.sub_4) {

                fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame,new cs206Fragment());
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("CS206");
                getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("Object Oriented Design and Programming");

            } else if (id == R.id.sub_5) {

                fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame,new cs208Fragment());
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("CS208");
                getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("Principles of data base design");

            } else if (id == R.id.sub_6) {

                fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame,new hs200Fragment());
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("HS200");
                getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("Buisness Economics");

            } else if (id == R.id.sub_7) {

                fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame,new hs210Fragment());
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("HS210");
                getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("Life Skills");

            } else if (id == R.id.lab_1) {

                fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame,new cs232Fragment());
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("CS232");
                getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("Free and open system software lab");

            } else if (id == R.id.lab_2) {

                fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame,new cs234Fragment());
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("CS234");
                getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("Digital systems lab");

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {

                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),About.class));

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                myIntent.setType("text/plain");
                String shareBody = "KTU CSE S4 app download from the given link : link (use chrome browser)";
                String shareSub = "Download KTU CSE S4 app";
                myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,shareSub);
                myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,shareBody);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(myIntent, "Share KTU CSE S4 app via"));

            }

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

            if (isopen)
            {
                university.startAnimation(Fabclose);
                ktuweb.startAnimation(Fabclose);
                drive.startAnimation(Fabclose);
                fab.startAnimation(Fabanticlockwise);
                fab_univer.startAnimation(Fabclose);
                fab_web.startAnimation(Fabclose);
                fab_drive.startAnimation(Fabclose);
                dim.startAnimation(dimoff);
                dim.setClickable(false);
                fab_web.setClickable(false);
                fab_univer.setClickable(false);
                fab_drive.setClickable(false);
                isopen = false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: please check answer here. link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18475419/how-to-open-navigationdrawer-on-first-app-start

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // your other code...
    // setContentView(...) initialize drawer and stuff like that...

    // use thread for performance
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            SharedPreferences sp = Context.getSharedPreferences("yoursharedprefs", 0);
            boolean isFirstStart = sp.getBoolean("key", true); 
            // we will not get a value  at first start, so true will be returned

            // if it was the first app start
            if(isFirstStart) {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
                Editor e = sp.edit(); 
                // we save the value "false", indicating that it is no longer the first appstart
                e.putBoolean("key", false);
                e.commit();
            }
        }           
    });

    t.start();
}
```